# What's the difference between parentheses and braces in c++ when constructing objects

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

What's the difference between `()` and `{}` when constructing objects?

I think {} should only support with `initializer_list` or  an array, but when I run below snip, I confused.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S {
    int v=0;
    S(int l) : v(l) {
    }
};


int main()
{
    S s1(12); // statement1
    S s2{12}; // statement2
    cout << s1.v << endl;
    cout << s2.v << endl;
}
```

`statement1` is right because `()` is the basic grammar for constructing the object.

I expect the `statement2` will be compiled failed. I think `{}` is only can be used for an array or `initializer_list` type. but the actual result is compiled perfectly without error.

what do I mis?

Comment: you miss uniform initialization, if you never heard about it you should search for it, it was a big thing in c++11

Comment: And I personally recommend to avoid it: `std::vector<int> v{10, 12}` – what do you think it will produce? With `std::vector<int> v(10, 12)` and `std::vector<int> v({10, 12})` everything just more clear...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `S`, they have the same effect. Both invoke the constructor `S::S(int)` to initialize the objects.

`S s2{12};` is regared as [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11); `S` is not an aggregate type and not `std::initializer_list`, and has no constructor taking `std::initializer_list`, then

> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of `T` participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed.

and you thought that

> I think `{}` is only can be used for an array or `initializer_list` type.

This is not true. The effect of list-initialization is that, e.g. if `S` is an aggregate type, then aggregate initialization is performed; if `S` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list`, then it's initialized as a `std::initializer_list`; if `S` has a constructor taking `std::initializer_list`, then it will be preferred to be used for initialization. You can refer to [the page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) linked for more precise details.

PS: `S s1(12);` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).