# implicit pointer argument in custom deleter for smart shared pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, arguments, smart-pointers

I want to ask a question about custom deleters in C++.

I have been learning OOP and smart pointers to take care of initialising and deleting objects pointed to by pointers on the heap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Test {
private:
    int data;
public:
    Test() : data {0} {std::cout << "\tTest constructor (" << data << ")" << std::endl;}
    Test(int data): data{data} {std::cout << "\tTest constructor (" << data << ")" << std::endl;}
    int get_data () const {return data;}
    ~Test() {std::cout << "\tTest destructor (" << data << ")" << std::endl;}
};

void my_deleter (Test *ptr) {
    std::cout << "\tUsing my custom function deleter" << std::endl;
    delete ptr;
}

int main () {
 {
     // using a function
    std::shared_ptr<Test> ptr1 {new Test {100}, my_deleter};
 }   
    std::cout << "====================" << std::endl;
    {
        // using a lambda
        std::shared_ptr<Test> ptr2 {new Test {1000}, 
        [] (Test *ptr) {
            std::cout << "\tUsing my custom lambda deleter" << std::endl;
            delete ptr;}
    };
    return 0;
}
}
```

If you look at the function `my_deleter` it expects an argument of type `Test` and a pointer.

However, when the code is executed in the smart pointer initialisation, the pointer itself isn't passed in as an argument.

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> ptr1 {new Test {100}, my_deleter};
```

I'm confused here.

*Why is there no argument passed in here but the code still outputs what I require?*

**OUTPUT**

```
    Test constructor (100)
    Using my custom function deleter
    Test destructor (100)
====================
    Test constructor (1000)
    Using my custom lambda deleter
    Test destructor (1000)
```

My guess was that similar to OOP with the `this` pointer being implicit in C++, the smart pointer object is also implicit when the custom deleter is called after it goes out of scope, but I found nothing to support that statement.

***Why do I not need to provide an argument for the deleter inside the smart pointer initialisation?***

Comment: The argument to your deleter is the value held by the smart pointer.

Comment: `my_deleter` is not a function call - that needs parens. You're passing a function pointer, not evaluating the deleter there and then.

Comment: For the first question, are you asking about this: [What's the difference between parentheses and braces in c++ when constructing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57304873)?