# How can parentheses or braces in C++ change variable initial value?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

Just an instructive interview question: "What does this C++14 program print?"

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { int i; };
struct B { 
    A a{1}; 
    operator int() { return a.i; }
};

int main() { 
    B x({});
    B y{{}};
    std::cout << x << y;
}
```

And it actually prints `10`, meaning that the braces in the definition of `y` change its initial value. But how?

Comment: The first calls the default constructor which initialises `a` to 1, the second directly initialises `a` to 0

Comment: The dupe doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Good question.
@AlanBirtles: I know it has to do with aggregate initialization. Could you explain what each brace / parentheses mean?

Comment: @Bernd see the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304873/whats-the-difference-between-parentheses-and-braces-in-c-when-constructing-ob

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between parentheses and braces in c++ when constructing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304873/whats-the-difference-between-parentheses-and-braces-in-c-when-constructing-ob)